# Warning message; while using quickly pacakge

Tags: command-line, application-development, quickly

I made my first UBUNTU application today.

Kindly see the warning message below;

```
$ quickly package
......
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  mybrows/MybrowsWindow.py~
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]:
```

Is it safe to continue ?

What does this error mean ? What is the correct way ?

Comment: Files ending in "~" tend to be backup files from your text editor. Remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900281/warning-message-while-using-quickly-pacakge#comment1411781_900281) the file you mentioned is likely a backup file created by your text editor that you don't need and removing it and trying again should do the trick. If not it appears that [DistUtilsExtra adds some extra "magic" rules based on filenames and content.](https://answers.launchpad.net/quickly/+question/139834)Sadly I could not find any information on what those "magic" rules actually are.

There is however information on specifying the files to distribute via a manifest [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest)

If the unrecognized file is already specified properly in `MANIFEST.in` you may be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/+bug/893335)